# Can't change text when combobox item changes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

Upon selecting and item in combo box, like iphone5,samsung s3,htc etc.. if a user selects Iphone5 the description of the item selected will be added to the textbox.

It seems to not work properly because every time I select a different item, it show's only the description that assigned to iphone5.

```
    If cboBrand.Items.Contains("Iphone5") = True Then

         TxtBox1.Text = "OS : iOS 6, upgradable to iOS 6.1, Chipset: Apple A6, CPU: Dual-core 1.2 GHz"

    ElseIf cboBrand.Items.Contains("Sumsung s3") = True Then

        TxtBox1.Text = "Os: Android OS, (Ice Cream Sandwich), upgradeable to 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean, CPU: Quad-core 1.4 GHz Cortex-A9)"

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little better example than that especially if you have more to add... Use a case statement instead and declare your strings before hand...

```
  Private Sub cboBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboBrand.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim strIphone5 As String = "OS : iOS 6, upgradable to iOS 6.1, Chipset: Apple A6, CPU: Dual-core 1.2 GHz"
    Dim strSumPhone As String = "Os: Android OS, (Ice Cream Sandwich), upgradeable to 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean, CPU: Quad-core 1.4 GHz Cortex-A9)"

    Select Case cboBrand.SelectedItem

        Case "iphone5"
            txtAddress.Text = strIphone5
        Case "Sumsung s3"
            TextBox1.Text = strSumPhone

    End Select

  End Sub
```

Now if you copy and paste this, go to the end of this sub and add this to the end of it if it doesn't exist...

```
 Handles cboBrand.SelectedIndexChanged 'Sometimes when copied it looses its handlers..
```

Comment: wow. this help me a lot. many thanks sir. i've learn new technique.

Comment: Your welcome, if this works please be sure to up-vote the answer. Good luck!

Comment: i cant vote morethan 1, i need 15 reputation to vote morethan that. but then. im so glad that you help me. many thanks again sir.

Answer (score 1):

This will work... And the only reason that it is always showing the iphone 5 is because your combobox always contains this and this means it's always true...

```
  Private Sub cboBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboBrand.SelectedIndexChanged

    If cboBrand.SelectedItem = ("Iphone5") Then

        txtAddress.Text = "OS : iOS 6, upgradable to iOS 6.1, Chipset: Apple A6, CPU: Dual-core 1.2 GHz"

    ElseIf cboBrand.SelectedItem = ("Sumsung s3") Then

        TextBox1.Text = "Os: Android OS, (Ice Cream Sandwich), upgradeable to 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean, CPU: Quad-core 1.4 GHz Cortex-A9)"

    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Theres another way you can do it too... Just a second and I think it's much better because you could have many elseif statements...